# Will a ASP.NET session reader lock block a writer lock?

Tags: asp.net, session, locking, blocking

I found some description about writer lock and reader lock blocking behavior from Patrick's [Understanding session state modes + FAQ](http://forums.asp.net/post/7504.aspx):

> **Reader lock will block a writer lock; Reader lock will NOT block reader lock; Writer lock will block all reader and writer lock.**

I designed some tests to prove "writer lock will block all reader and writer lock" and "reader lock will not block reader lock" successfully.  But in my test, it seems "reader lock WILL NOT block writer lock either" (there is more detail about the test in [my post](http://blog.darkthread.net/post-2011-08-31-asp-net-session-reader-lock-blocking.aspx)) and I didn't find more researches on this issue, has anybody ever proven it?

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)

> If the EnableSessionState value in the @ Page directive is set to
>   ReadOnly, **a request for the read-only session information does not
>   result in an exclusive lock on the session data**. However, read-only
>   requests for session data might still have to wait for a lock set by a
>   read-write request for session data to clear.

Comment: Thanks for your information, I have read this while trying to find hint and I am still curious, I guess it's still possible that a non-exclusive lock could block a exclusive block (writer lock), like Patrick's point.

Comment: Yes if EnableSessionState is not set to readonly is my understanding. In which case a read is an exclusive lock.

Comment: TheCodeKing, according to your understanding, do you think the reader lock (EnableSessionState="ReadOnly") will block a exclusive writer lock or not? (I appreciate your opinion)

Comment: MSDN says, with EnableSessionState = ReadOnly, the read does not block writer. This makes sense, if it knows it's readonly, then it doesn't need to exclusively lock. The last sentence says the read may be blocked by other read-writes.